# SQlite increment field and not exists

Tags: sqlite

My SQLite code works with this, incrementing my count, and adding foo to my database:

```
INSERT or REPLACE into masterWords  (words, count) 
values ("foo", coalesce ((select count + 1 
from masterWords where  words = "foo" ), 1))
```

but when I add NOT EXISTS, count no longer increments.

```
INSERT or REPLACE into masterWords  (words, count) 
values ("foo", coalesce ((select count + 1 
from masterWords where  words = "foo" ), 1)  
AND  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT mWord 
from mWords where mWords.mWord = "foo" ))
```

table: masterWords contains column words, count
table: mWords contains the column mWord

I'm stumped, any ideas to get my count incrementing again?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT or REPLACE into masterWords  (words, count) 
values ("foo", coalesce ((select count + 1 
from masterWords where  words = "foo" ), 1  
AND  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT DISTINCT mWord 
from mWords where mWords.mWord = "foo" )))
```

Just needed to a move bracket. As long as there are no objections thought i'd leave the question and solution as might be of use to someone.